# check if android version is less than 4 with phonegap?

Tags: cordova

Im trying to check if the android version is less than 4 with phonegap.

Im getting the version with this.

```
   var deviceOS  = device.platform;  //fetch the device operating system
   var deviceOSVersion = device.version;  //fetch the device OS version
          alert("Device OS: " + deviceOS); 
          alert("Device OS Version: " + deviceOSVersion);
```

And trying to check if the version is less than 4 with this, but it is not working?

```
if (deviceOSVersion < 4) {
    alert("android less than 4");
}
```

I have tested a few thing but no luck.
Any input appreciated thanks.

UPDATE:
Im trying to set the last code "useAnimations:animationen" to false if it is and android less than 4 and if it is an iPhone the "animationen" should be true. 
But on the iPhone it is false with the below code?

```
 var int = 0;
    var animationen='';

  function onBodyLoad()
        {         
       document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
        }

        function onDeviceReady()
        {
    getDeviceProperty();
        }

    function getDeviceProperty(){
     var deviceOS  = device.platform;  //fetch the device operating system
     var deviceOSVersion = device.version;  //fetch the device OS version
          alert("Device OS: " + deviceOS); 
          alert("Device OS Version: " + deviceOSVersion); 


if (deviceOS.indexOf('Android') >= 0) {
alert("its an android");
int = parseInt(deviceOSVersion);
if(int<4){
alert("animation false");
animationen=false;
}
alert("apptype = android");
}
else
{
alert("apptype = iphone");
animationen=true;
}                     
}


var jQT = new $.jQTouch({
useAnimations: animationen
});
```

Answer (score 6):

You need to parseInt the value received by using,

```
if( parseInt( deviceOSVersion, 10 ) < 4 )
{
    // your code
}
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Actually you could simply do a string comparison: `deviceOSVersion < "4"`

Comment: @user276648 no that wont work you have to either parse as float or int (if you don't care about minor or patch). You can also include semver package but this seems sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

```
var int = 0;  
....// your code here
int = parseInt(deviceOSVersion);
if(int<4){
//do something
}
```

I've checked and it's working.

Comment: Thanks guys. It works but I still have a problem. I will update my code and explain.